# amplify configure - error: uncaughtException: spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: node.js, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

error on amplify configure - error: uncaughtException: spawn cmd ENOENT

C:\Users\Home>amplify configure

Follow these steps to set up access to your AWS account:

Sign in to your AWS administrator account:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/

Press Enter to continue

```
2020-07-18T09:41:08.083Z - error: uncaughtException: spawn cmd ENOENT date=Sat J
ul 18 2020 15:11:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), pid=4536, uid=null, gid=null
, cwd=C:\Users\Home, execPath=C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nod
e\bin\node.exe, version=v10.0.0, argv=[C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\node\bin\node.exe, C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amp
lify\cli\bin\amplify, configure], rss=290361344, heapTotal=251351040, heapUsed=2
07170688, external=2257815, loadavg=[0, 0, 0], uptime=6909, trace=[column=19, fi
le=internal/child_process.js, function=Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit, line
=217, method=onexit, native=false, column=16, file=internal/child_process.js, fu
nction=onErrorNT, line=394, method=null, native=false, column=19, file=internal/
process/next_tick.js, function=process._tickCallback, line=174, method=_tickCall
back, native=false, column=11, file=internal/modules/cjs/loader.js, function=Mod
ule.runMain, line=721, method=runMain, native=false, column=19, file=internal/bo
otstrap/node.js, function=startup, line=228, method=null, native=false, column=3
, file=internal/bootstrap/node.js, function=bootstrapNodeJSCore, line=575, metho
d=null, native=false], stack=[Error: spawn cmd ENOENT,     at Process.ChildProce
ss._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:217:19),     at onErrorNT (internal
/child_process.js:394:16),     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_t
ick.js:174:19),     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:7
21:11),     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19),     at bootstrapNode
JSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)]
```

installed node

installed @aws-amplify/cli

node version 12.0.0

amplify version 4.24.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add system32 to the PATH variable and see if it fixes your issue

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Windows/System32
```

and then run

```
amplify configure
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it did?

Comment: sure this URL has a detailed explanation: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1647

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu do:

sudo apt-get -y install xdg-utils